# Delay starting XNA game switching to Fullscreen messing up intro screen

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a Windows game using XNA 4.0. I have an quick little intro screen that shows our studio logo and plays a sound. It lasts 1.5 seconds and looks and works as desired in windowed mode.

We want to run the game full screen. So all I added was "graphics.IsFullScreen = true" to the Game subclass constructor after the GraphicsDeviceManager is instantiated and we've set the preferred backbuffer dimensions. When the game starts the video card just glitches my monitors for like 1 or 2 seconds switching resolutions, etc. - and that is all a customary and understandable delay between the video card, the device drivers and my monitors all figuring out this change, but XNA is running the game loop while all this nonsense is going on.

This means my intro starts, runs and is over by the time the system gets around to actually displaying what I'm drawing and by then the intro is over. What I'd really like is a way to detect when the video card is actually rendering before I start drawing and playing sound and timing things assuming the player can see them. Searching around online, I've seen reference to a "graphics.EnsureDevice()" call that seems to have been deprecated and is no longer available in XNA 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is kind of dirty, but you could fire off a thread that continually checks to see if the DeviceParameter IsFullscreen is set to true on active graphics device, after you set the GraphicsDeviceManager.IsFullscreen property to true.

Once it is set, then you would start your game loop.

You could also write it in a way that the thread would only fire off if you set GraphicsDeviceManager.IsFullscreen to true.  That way it would support both modes.